# keep iTunes and WMP playlists in sync

Tags: itunes, sync, windows-media-player, windows-media-center, playlists

I use media center for listening to music, however I also use itunes for keeping my iPod in sync. I often create playlists on the go on my iPod, but when I'm at home I prefer media center and often create playlists using that.

**What is the easiest way to have a single folder of playlists, that work on both platforms?**

In an ideal world, I would like a system that auto converts itunes playlists into m3u lists and sends them to a network location so that Windows media players can see and read them, and also, converts wmp playlists into itunes playlists and puts them into my itunes library.

I fear that there may not be an easy solution, so an alternative would be if I could easily convert itunes playlists into m3us, and convert m3us into whatever format itunes uses. This would be a bit of an annoying manual process, but if it is the only solution, then I can deal with that!

*please note: all my music is on a network drive (**X:\media\music\CDs**), and I would like to have my playlists all together in a folder on the same drive if possible (**X:\media\music\playlists**).*

Answer (score 2):

Google led me to [MusicBridge](http://sites.google.com/site/jrmwillis/):

> MusicBridge allows people who use both
>   iTunes and WMP on the same machine to
>   keep their libraries in sync.
>   MusicBridge offers a variety of
>   synchronization options so that you
>   can manage your music collection in
>   either media player or both.

Disclaimer: I have not used it yet, but planning to (as I have the exact same problem).

Comment: The programmer is an idiot. He neither updates his app nor makes it open source. I'm going to write my own app for this purpose.